# yahooquery premium user not logging in

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance

I am using yahooquery version is 2.3.1 and when running the below code I get an error. I installed yahooquery[premium]. I am certain my username and pw are correct. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['fb', 'aapl', 'amzn', 'nflx', 'goog']

faang = Ticker(symbols, asynchronous=True)
faang.login(username="my_user_name@yahoo.com", password="my_pw")

# You'll be logged in after about 15-20 seconds

# Access financial information for all quarters
income_statement = faang.p_income_statement('q')
cash_flow = faang.p_cash_flow('q')
balance_sheet = faang.p_balance_sheet('q')

# Retrieve the company 360 data
company_360 = faang.p_company_360

# Retrieve valuation_measures (annual, quarterly, monthly)
vma = faang.p_valuation_measures('a')
vmq = faang.p_valuation_measures('q')
vmm = faang.p_valuation_measures('m')

vma
```

Here is the error:

{'amzn': 'User is not logged in', 'fb': 'User is not logged in', 'goog': 'User is not logged in', 'nflx': 'User is not logged in', 'aapl': 'User is not logged in'}

I copied the code from the yahooquery examples and my username/pw from my yahoo log in.